# Codeigniter not uploading image files in png format

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, dropzone.js

Codeigniter 3.1.6 is the version i am using. when i try to upload files in jpg format it is successful but uploading files in png format is not working here is my code. I am using dropzone.js for the file uploading

**Views**

```
<form action="admin/addimg" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" style="margin-bottom: 5%; border: 2px dashed #0087F7; border-radius: 5px; background: white;" id="imgupld"></form>

<script>
Dropzone.options.imgupld = {
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 20, // MB
    acceptedFiles: "image/*", // Accept images only
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drag your image here"
};
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
function addimg()
    {
        if (!empty($_FILES))
        {
            $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = './assets/img/';
            $targetFile = $targetPath . $_FILES['file']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use codeigniter file upload library https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: do `print_r($_FILES);` see what error there is.

Comment: @Mr.ED sadly idk how i've been trying to can you show me a possible codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with the  use of CI upload library.First you nedd to load library either in config->autoload.php

```
    $autoload['libraries'] = array('upload');
```

or in your controller.Example

```
    class ImageUpload extends CI_Controller
    {
       public function Upload()
       {
          if($_FILES["uploadImage"]["error"]==4)//check if user select input any image to upload
          {
               $config['Upload_Path']='';//File upload path
               $config['allowed_types']='jpeg|jpg|png';//set the preferred  file formats here
               $config['max_size']=100000;// Max File Size

               if($this->upload->do_upload('uploadImage'))//uploading the data
                {
                    $uploadData=$this->upload->data();//get the details of uploaded data
                }else
                {
                   $error=$this->upload->display_errors();//this return the error message if any error thrown 
                }
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Just to point out your class naming wrong in latest version for codeigniter only the first letter should be upper case on filename and class name explained here Or though it may work on some systems best to name it codeigniter way as in user guide https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: I saw the errors turns out my file was exceeding php maximum file size thanks for your code